# Linq to DataSet Order By Clause Error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have following code that creates Linq query. 
I've never used Linq until today (shame on me) and having problem with "Order By Clause"

```
    Dim products = dt.AsEnumerable()
    Dim linq = From p In products _
               Where p!Weight > 2 _
               Take 20 _
               Select p!Clarity, p!Color, p!Weight _
               Order By p!Weight.Length
```

If I run the code, I get following error.

Name 'p' is either not declared or not in the current scope.

How come p!Weight in "Select Clause" works but not in "Order By Clause"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `Select` clause, `p` is no longer in scope.
Move the `Order By` first.

Comment: Great! I was referring this site. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738037#ordbysimp1 Select clause should go the last always??

Comment: @shinya: You can put the `Order By` after the `Select`, but it will only have access to the fields in the `Select`.